# MySQL tz_convert utc returning null?

Tags: mysql

I was using tz_convert() function from MySQL and I am getting Null.

Is this normal. I was reading that is bug ?

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','PST','UTC') as date;
```

Comment: Using timezone or location names in MySQL convert_tz() is dependant on how the system timezone database is configured. If you now the offsets, pass them in '+00:00' format instead of tz names. That should work regardless of the system configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timezone or location names in MySQL convert_tz() is dependant on how the system timezone database is configured. If you know the offsets, pass them in '+00:00' format instead of tz names. That should work regardless of the system configuration. E.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','-08:00','+00:00') as date;
```

Comment: Yes, I was doing something like that except SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+08:00','+00:00')  Thanks for the info.